# Отмена растягивания изображения в scrollview

Tags: java, android

Имеется ScrollView Activity с таким кодом:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:background="IMG"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="CLK"
        android:duplicateParentState="false"
        app:titleEnabled="false">



    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

При смене ротации экрана, картинка растягивается, и получается не очень красиво, можно как-то отменить растягивание картинки?

Answer (score 0):

Не надо ставить `background` картинку в `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. Создайте `ImageView` с картинкой и поместите его внутрь `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.